# Camel process do not shutdown because of (not existing) inflight exchanges

Tags: java, apache-camel, kestrel

I've a Camel process (that I run from command line) which route is similar to this one:

```
public class ProfilerRoute extends RouteBuilder {

 @Override
 public void configure() {   
    from("kestrel://my_queue?concurrentConsumers=10&waitTimeMs=500")
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, MyClass.class)
        .process(new Processor() {
                 @Override
                 public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                     /* Do the real processing [...] */
                     exchange.getIn().setBody(null);
                 }
        })
        .filter(body().isNotNull())
        .to("file://nowhere");
 }
}
```

Note that I'm trashing whatever message after having processed it, being this a pure consumer
process.

The process is run by its own. No other process is writing on the queue, the queue is empty. 
However when I try to kill the process the process is not going to die.

From the logs I see the following lines (indented for readability):

```
[                      Thread-1] MainSupport$HangupInterceptor  INFO  
                                 Received hang up - stopping the main instance.
[                      Thread-1] MainSupport                    INFO
                                 Apache Camel stopping
[                      Thread-1] GuiceCamelContext              INFO
                                 Apache Camel 2.11.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) 
                                 is shutting down
[                      Thread-1] DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO
                                 Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes 
                                 (timeout 300 seconds)
[l-1) thread #12 - ShutdownTask] DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO
                                 Waiting as there are still 10 inflight and 
                                 pending exchanges to complete, 
                                 timeout in 300 seconds.
```

And so on with decreasing timeout. At the end of the timeout I get on the logs:

```
[l-1) thread #12 - ShutdownTask] DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO
                                 Waiting as there are still 10 inflight and 
                                 pending exchanges to complete,
                                 timeout in 1 seconds.
[                      Thread-1] DefaultShutdownStrategy        WARN
                                 Timeout occurred. 
                                 Now forcing the routes to be shutdown now.
[l-1) thread #12 - ShutdownTask] DefaultShutdownStrategy        WARN
                                 Interrupted while waiting during graceful 
                                 shutdown, will force shutdown now.
[                      Thread-1] KestrelConsumer                INFO  
                                 Stopping consumer for 
                                 kestrel://localhost:22133/my_queue?concurrentConsumers=10&waitTimeMs=500
```

But the process will not die anyway (even if I try to kill it at this point).

I would have expected that after the waiting time all the threads would realise that a shutdown is going on and stop.

I've read the ["Graceful Shutdown"](http://camel.apache.org/graceful-shutdown.html) document, however I could not find something that explains the behaviour I'm facing.

As you can see from logs I'm using the 2.11.1 version of Apache Camel.

**UPDATE:** According to Claus Ibsen it might be a problem of the camel-kestrel component. I filed a issue on ASF Jira for Camel: [CAMEL-6632](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6632)

Comment: Could be a bug in the camel-kestrel component. Can you try change the concurrentConsumers=1 and see if that helps. And also if you set it to =5 does Camel says there is 5 inlfight messages?

Comment: With concurrentConsumer=1 everything works. With concurrentConsumer=5 same problem with 5 inflight messages. I think (although I'm not utterly sure) that this problem arose after passing from 2.10.x to 2.11.x.

Comment: Feel free to log a JIRA at Apache Camel about this bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in camel-kestrel, and a JIRA ticket has been logged to fix this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6632